# Google sheets JSON data

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am new in c#. I have JSON data like below. Furthermore, I got it by converting from Google sheets. I am trying to make a leaderboard for my unity game. But I can't assign these "values" to the variable. I want to get "Name", "Score", "Event" and I want to assign them to a variable.

```
{
  "range": "Sheet1!A1:M112",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "Time",
      "Name",
      "Surname",
      "E-Mail",
      "Company / University",
      "Event(Optional)",
      "Score"
    ],
    [
      "12.06.2023 11:17:09",
      "Henry",
      "Powell",
      "@hotmail.com",
      "x Company",
      "x Event",
      "0"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have structure like this. Furthermore, I can print `majorDimension` and range. I don't understand list inside list concept in c# so i can't reach "values" section. You can see what i tried in getData section.

```
public struct Data{
    public string range;
    public string majorDimension;
    public List<List<string>> values;
}
```

```
IEnumerator getData()
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(googleSheetURL);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Data data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data>(www.downloadHandler.text);

            Debug.Log(data.values);
            Debug.Log(data.majorDimension);
            Debug.Log(data.range);
        }

        www.Dispose();
    }
```

I will be glad if you help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code for example

```
    List<List<string>> values = data.values;

    int NameIndex = values[0].IndexOf("Name");
    int EventIndex = values[0].Select((ev, index) => (ev, index))
                              .First(ev => ev.ev.Contains("Event")).index;
    int ScoreIndex = values[0].IndexOf("Score");

var scores = values.Select((ev, index) => (ev, index)).Where(v => v.index > 0)
                            .Select(e =>  new
                            {
                            name = e.ev[NameIndex],
                            ev = e.ev[EventIndex],
                            score = e.ev[ScoreIndex]
                           }).ToList();
```

but I highly recommend you do download and install Newtonsoft.Json for Unity3d (google it). In this case you can  deserialize a json string using this code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(www.downloadHandler.text);
```

But to use Newtonsoft don't forget to add {get; set;} to all properties of your Data class

Comment: I can't do it, I can get json data as text and i can print. is there a way to split this json data as you see above?

Comment: @ozzyys What data is this? can you post it Data data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Data>(www.downloadHandler.text);     Debug.Log(data.values);

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wu1RzIrdB7A30JL7N5w23jabr11AMCPU/view?usp=sharing) I have to parse the data. The players send the information like "Name", "Surname". "Score" is sended automatically. I am using google forms to write them to google sheets. Then, I get the data from google sheets as JSON text. I want to just get player name, score and event. But I can't parse JSON data. Now, In the file, I shared with you, the rows are filled random. But the titles are correct. Thank you Mr. Serge for your help.

Comment: [codes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gvkKj5Kn6tkjPGIZ4LPYwLCxPA3ec2pb/view?usp=sharing) Here is the code which I use for print the values. But this code printing empty lines. These empty lines number equal to my google sheets rows.

Comment: I did it thanks to your newtonsoft suggestion. Thanks for everything Mr. Serge. Have a nice day!